# If value is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that saves the users input into local storage and then prints the value into the selected ID.

```
function saveData() { 
var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");
localStorage.setItem("server", input.value);  
console.log(localStorage.getItem("server"));
document.getElementById("yourname").innerHTML ="Okay &nbsp;" + (localStorage.getItem("server")) + "&nbsp; Let's get started! Push the button on the right to begin the story!"  ;   
}
```

How do I make it so if the input field is empty a statement is produced informing the user to input their name.

I've had a look at if and else statements but anything I try doesn't seem to work.

Edit:

Figured it out!

```
if (saveServer.value == "")  {
document.getElementById("yourname").innerHTML = "Please input your name";
} 

else {   
document.getElementById("yourname").innerHTML ="Okay &nbsp;" + (localStorage.getItem("server")) + "&nbsp; Let's get started! Push the button on the right to begin the story!"  ;   
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried. It's as simple as `if (input.value) { /* store value */ } else { /* show info */ }`, which you probably tried and which should "work". If it doesn't (for you) you have to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check if input not empty.

```
function saveData() { 
var input = document.getElementById("saveServer").value;
if(input ==="") alert("Enter saveServer");
else{
  localStorage.setItem("server", input.value);  
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("server"));
  document.getElementById("yourname").innerHTML ="Okay &nbsp;" + (localStorage.getItem("server")) + "&nbsp; Let's get started! Push the button on the right to begin the story!"  ;   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function saveData() {
    var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");
    localStorage.setItem("server", input.value);
    var serverValue = localStorage.getItem("server");
    if (!serverValue) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Oh dear! Nothing was found";
    }
    document.getElementById("yourname").innerHTML = "Okay &nbsp;" +     (localStorage.getItem("server")) + "&nbsp; Let's get started! Push the button on the right to begin the story!";
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/LhyXr/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I managed to figure it out on my own and it works fine. Is your way better than mine? or does it not matter?